# angular 2 - ngfor with condition in()

Tags: angular, ionic2

i need make the condition in angular2 with ngfor.
This condition in sql is

```
select foo from fos where id in (@params)
```

I need make this in angular2 with `*ngFor`, I have this code

```
 <form>
    <ion-list *ngFor="let g of grids">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <div class="table-responsive">

        </div>

    </ion-list>
</form>
```

And this function, But it only receive one parameter

```
getGrid(id: number): Array<{ title: string, id: any }> {
    return this.grids.filter(grids => grids.id == id);
}
```

How make for receive more params `getgrid(1,2,4)`? (example)

Answer (score 0):

You can have it accept an array like this:

```
getGrid(ids: number[]): Array<{ title: string, id: any }> {
    return this.grids.filter(grid => ids.indexOf(grids.id) !== -1);
}
```

Usage:

```
getGrid([1,2,4]);
```

Or use the `...` notation to combine the arguments in an array:

```
getGrid(...ids: number[]): Array<{ title: string, id: any }> {
    return this.grids.filter(grid => ids.indexOf(grids.id) !== -1);
}
```

With the latter option you can call the method like you mentioned:

```
getGrid(1,2,4);
```